# Term for a font that leaves no loose parts

Tags: font-recommendation, terminology

I am trying to figure out what term to use when searching for fonts that are open so that centers of o's, a's, p's etc. will be attached to the background when I use them in cut files.

Comment: Hi Linda, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 7):

That's called a *stencil font*.